# Any way to synchronize 2 mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, database

Two machines, each running mysql, each synchronized to the other peer-to-peer.  I do not want a master db replicated. Rather, I want two users to be able to work on the data offline (each running a mysql server on his machine) and then when reconnected synchronize to each other.   Any way to do this with mysql?  Any other database I should be looking at to accomplish this better than mysql?

Comment: What do you mean by "Any other database option?"

Comment: Synchronized how? Data, or schema, or both? If it's just data, I'm guessing you've already looked at mysql replication? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Are you looking for mySQL Clustering?

Comment: Data or schema if possible. I want no master db, only peers. I want them to be able to operate on a laptop offline.  When they are connected then synchronize to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-way replication is provided by various database systems (e.g. SQLServer, Sybase etc.) but there are always problems with such a set up.

For example, if the same row is updated at the same time on the two databases, which update wins?

If your aim is to provide a highly-available MySQL database, then there are better options than using replication. MySQL has a clustering solution (though I've not had much success with it) or you can use things like DRBD and heartbeat to provide automatic failover with no loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean synchronous writing back and forth, this would cause serious data consistency issues. I think you may be referring to MySQL replication, wherein a master server sends its updates to one or more slave database servers, which can be queried.

Comment: Yes I mean the first, not a master replicating out to slaves. I want to be able to have two databases independent so they can be used offline and then synchronized when the 2 machines are connected again.

Answer (score 0):

As for "Other Database Options" SQLServer supports a fairly advanced "replication" process for synchronizing the data between two or more db's. Looks like MySql has something like this as well though.